# SQL subquery error not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

My SQL query is giving error while trying to execute query:

> Error: 
>   Query input must contain at least one table or query

```
INSERT into Posts (PostText,TimePosted, TID) 
       VALUES ('My Post','2013-04-11 13:50:18',
             (SELECT MAX(TID) FROM Threads AS TID))
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine the literal fields with the select & move the alias;

```
INSERT into Posts (PostText,TimePosted, TID) 
   SELECT 'My Post','2013-04-11 13:50:18', MAX(TID) AS TID FROM Threads
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified table name in your query.

There are 3 fields in your table and you are sending 3 values (Last value by select query).

But you have not written table name for main query in which data to insert.

Comment: Surely it's `Posts` - `INSERT into Posts`... ?

Comment: english is not my primary language, sorry, i think sends